# php mysql update error

Tags: php, mysql

code :

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
mysql_select_db('share_counter');  

$sql_insert = "UPDATE wpshare SET '$social_name'='45' where post_title = '$post_title' ";
mysql_query($sql_insert) or die(mysql_error());
```

error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near
>   ''twitter_count'='45' where post_title
>   = 'test'' at line 1

thanks advance

Answer (score 2):

omit the quotes over `$social_name`

```
$sql_insert = "UPDATE wpshare SET $social_name='45' where post_title = '$post_title' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

quotes around the column names (aka $social_name) should be like this ` not like this '

```
so $sql_insert = "UPDATE wpshare SET `$social_name`='45' where post_title = '$post_title' ";
```

and if your column names have no spaces , you can just remove the quotes ...

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_insert = "UPDATE `wpshare` SET `$social_name`='45' WHERE `post_title` = '$post_title'";
```

Comment: Backticks are only necessary when the table/field names are mysql reserved words.